# Returning Value from PHP Function Problem

Tags: php, function

I am having a problem returning a value from my function. I think ive setup it to return $filename, but it doesn't I get a blank value when it is returned. Did I make a mistake somewhere? I assigned the imageupload function to the variable $newfilename and then try to insert into my db and I get no data in the column for that record.

imageupload function:

```
    function imageupload()
{
    $allowed_types=array(
    'image/gif',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png',
    'image/pjpeg',
    );

if (($_FILES["picupload"]["size"] < 5500000))
  {
      if(in_array($_FILES["picupload"]["type"], $allowed_types))
      {
        if ($_FILES["picupload"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception('Invalid File - No Data In File');
        }
        else
        {
            $dirname = getcwd() . '/userpics/' . $_SESSION['username'];
            if (!file_exists($dirname)) 
            {
                $thisdir = getcwd()  . "/userpics/" . $_SESSION['username']; 

                if(mkdir($thisdir , 0777)) 
                { 
                    $filename = basename( $_FILES['picupload']['name']);
                    $ext = end(explode(".", $filename));
                    $thisdir = getcwd()  . "/userpics/" . $_SESSION['username'] . "/profilepic." . $ext;
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picupload']['tmp_name'], $thisdir)) 
                    {
                        return $ext;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception('Could not upload file');
                    }
                } 
                else 
                { 
                   throw new Exception('Could not create directory');
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                $filename = basename( $_FILES['picupload']['name']);
                $ext = end(explode(".", $filename));
                $thisdir = getcwd()  . "/userpics/" . $_SESSION['username'] . "/profilepic." . $ext;
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picupload']['tmp_name'], $thisdir)) 
                {
                    return $ext;
                } 
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception('Could not upload file');
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Invalid File Type');
    }
  }
else
  {
    throw new Exception('Invalid File Error, File Too Large');
  } 
}
```

Code Calling Imageupload:

```
else if ($type == "update")
{
    if($_POST['changeimage'] == 'true')
    {
        $newfilename = imageupload();
        $sql="UPDATE users SET `FirstName`='$_POST[firstname]', `MiddleInt`='$_POST[middleint]', `LastName`='$_POST[lastname]', `emailAddress`='$_POST[emailaddress]', `website`='$_POST[website]', `Title`='$_POST[title]', `College`='$_POST[collegedropdown]', `Department`='$_POST[deptdropdown]', `Phone`='$_POST[phone]', `Photo`='$newfilename' WHERE `uid` = '$uid';";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql="UPDATE users SET `FirstName`='$_POST[firstname]', `MiddleInt`='$_POST[middleint]', `LastName`='$_POST[lastname]', `emailAddress`='$_POST[emailaddress]', `website`='$_POST[website]', `Title`='$_POST[title]', `College`='$_POST[collegedropdown]', `Department`='$_POST[deptdropdown]', `Phone`='$_POST[phone]' WHERE `uid` = '$uid';";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error, please contact the administrator";
}
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);mysql_close($con);
//header("location: index.php");

}
```

Comment: Sidenote: you have several sql injection vulnerabilities in that code.

Comment: @Dogbert I have yet to add that protection that was next on my list after getting the function working properly thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: You don't have a matching `else` for when the file isn't in the allowed file types. Although that should cause the return value to be `NULL` in PHP, IIRC.

Comment: Instead of writing your function as a nested if-else tree (and apparently forgetting a branch), you should write it as `function f() {if(!condition1) {throw new Exception("cond1 failed");} if(!condition2) {throw new Exception("cond2 failed");} return result;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your code.

At first, you're referencing `$_FILES['file']`. But after that, you're referencing `$_FILES['picupload']`.

Secondly, `$allowed_types` is not defined.

Also, `getcwd()` usually won't return a trailing slash. So this:

```
$thisdir = getcwd() . 'userpics/' . $_SESSION['username'];
```

...will probably not work. This:

```
$ext = end(explode(".", $filename));
```

...is illegal. `end` accepts a reference. As such, you cannot pass the result of a function to it. You should store it in a variable first. However, this is the best way to achieve the same thing is to use `pathinfo`.

At some point, you're wrongly doing a `file_exists($thisdir)` **then** `mkdir($thisdir)`. You're also not appending a filename to the directory afterwards.

You're unnecessarily duplicating code and using `if...else` with exceptions. You should refactor (it will also make it easier to debug):

```
function imageupload()
{
    // define $allowed_types
    $allowed_types = array('image/png'); 

    // use "picupload" here
    if ($_FILES["picupload"]["size"] >= 5500000)
        throw new Exception('Invalid File Error, File Too Large');

    if (!in_array($_FILES["picupload"]["type"], $allowed_types))
        throw new Exception('File type not allowed');

    if ($_FILES["picupload"]["error"] > 0)
        throw new Exception('Invalid File - No Data In File');

    // fix the getcwd() expression
    $thisdir = getcwd() . '/userpics/' . $_SESSION['username'];

    // create the directory only if it doesn't exist
    if (!file_exists($thisdir)) {
        if (!mkdir($thisdir, 0777))
            throw new Exception('Could not create directory');
    }

    $filename = basename($_FILES['picupload']['name']);

    // fix the end(explode()) illegal call
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // make sure this is actually a filename, and not a directory
    $thisdir .= "/profilepic." . $ext;

    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picupload']['tmp_name'], $thisdir))
        throw new Exception('Could not upload file');

    return $filename;
}
```

*Note: As mentionned in the comments, the caller code is also vulnerable to SQL injection.*

Comment: 1) That was typo on my part not an error in the code. 2) the array is not relevant here, I dint include the whole program code as you should see. 3) Thank you for point out the missing '/' 4) $filename was used I updated it change the first one to $dirname thus the second is define as a variable that gets basename. 5) You need to check prior to the creation of the directory otherwise it will return an error, perhaps you could point how this is wrong? As Noted before that is just a directory and not the file name. It still returns a value of "" after all your suggestions.

Comment: With the above code, it's *impossible* for the function to not return anything. The `mkdir` part is wrong because you check if it exists, and if it does, you create it: it will always fail. And yes, `$allowed_types` is actually relevant to the question.